# How to implement an image gallery inside an application mimicking the iPhone's default gallery?

Tags: iphone, ios, image-gallery

I want to implement an image gallery inside my iPhone app which will only have those images from device gallery that have been either selected from inside the app or pictures taken from inside the app. Please advice on any simple methods to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [Three20](http://three20.info/), it's a very nice framework for doing such a task.

Here is some piece of sample code you can use.

In interface :

```
//IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
UIImagePickerController *imgPicker;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;
```

Then in viewDidLoad :

```
self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imgPicker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
//self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
//imgarry = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"terms.png",@"change-profile.png",nil];
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img,nil,nil,nil);
```

Then in buttonClick :

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
imgPicker.delegate = self;
imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
[imgPicker release];
```

This is how i achieve this, don't forget to set @property and @synthesis for image-view and UIImagePicker.

Comment: i have seen that actually. its bit complex and i am just a beginner, so would like something simpler. besides i am going to need to pick images from the default gallery, don't know how to do that stuff

Comment: i think u just want to display images from default iphone image gallery right?

Comment: IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
 UIImagePickerController *imgPicker;
 IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;

Comment: @nandu please look at my answer ,there may be some syntax error but its the right way.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Three20](http://three20.info/) or [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView).

Answer (score -1):

You can use UIScrollView with paging=YES.